# C++ Have array values in an enum?

Tags: c++, arrays, enums

I was wondering if it is possible to have an array value in an enum? Example

```
    enum RGB {
      RED[3],
      BLUE[3]

    } color;
```

That way `RED` could contain values of `(255,0,0)` since that is the RGB color code for red.

Comment: Enums aren't really meant to contain values. you could have a `static const int enumValues[numColors][3]` containing colors corresponding to enums. You still can do `enum  RGB { RED = 0xff000, BLUE=0x00ff00, ...}`.

Comment: yeah I know in worst case scenario I would just use that instead. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

No you can't do that with an enum. It looks a lot like you want a class/struct:

```
class Color {
public:
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;

    Color(int r, int g, int b) : red(r), green(g), blue(b) { }
};
```

Once you have that class defined, you can then put it into a container (e.g. array, vector) and look them up. You could use an enum to refer to elements in an array, for example.

```
enum PresetColor {
    PRESET_COLOR_RED,
    PRESET_COLOR_GREEN,
    PRESET_COLOR_BLUE,
};

...
Color presetColors[] = { Color(255, 0, 0), Color(0, 255, 0), Color(0, 0, 255) };

Color favouriteColor = presetColors[PRESET_COLOR_GREEN];
```

With that in mind, you could wrap all this up to be more maintainable, but I would say that's out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that. The tokens in an `enum` can only hold integral values.

A possible solution:

```
struct Color {uint8_t r; uint8_t g; uint8_t b;}; 

Color const RED = {255, 0, 0};
Color const GREEN = {0, 255, 0};
Color const BLUE = {0, 0, 255};
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a long story short: NO, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, the definition of enums only allows for them to hold integer values.